# Catching the EOF keystroke without pressing Enter C

Tags: c, eof, keystroke, getch

I am writing a program which has a main menu, with a couple functions which I am allowing the user to access by typing in a number for one menu selections. For that, I am using _getch(). I need to be able to exit the program when the user enters the EOF key, but  _getch() does not actually catch the EOF keystroke. I know I can get it to work by using getchar() instead of _getch(), but I would prefer not to have the user be forced to press enter after every function selection.

Is there a way to get _getch() to catch EOF? This is for Windows if it is of any importance, any help is really appreciated, as I have been unable to find anything out there.

Answer (score 0):

The standard C input stream `stdio` is line buffered, and there is no defined way to forcibly flush it. If you want to avoid this and read from the buffer as every new character is entered, you have to use some OS specific magic, which is what `_getch` from `conio.h` tries to do.

There are other implementations out there of `getch`-type functions, for instance `getch` from the [PDCurses library](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/).